# Detect SplitContainer's select Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Windows Form named `Form1` and inside I have a dynamic  `SplitContainer` named `splitcontainer`.

I want to know which panel is selected when the mouse is clicked at runtime.
I tried to use `mouseclick` event in the splitContainer properties but I haven't succeed.

Comment: When you say "when the mouse is clicked".. do you mean when you click to select a panel?

Comment: yes my bro Wheels73, when i click the select panel

Comment: Ok - see my answer. I think its what you need. thanks

Comment: thanks but me i create the spliter dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind to the MouseClick events of the panel inside the split container.

I added a container called "splitContainer1" with 2 panels, Panel1 and 2

I wired up the below events and it seems to work

```
        private void splitContainer1_Panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Panel1");
        }

        private void splitContainer1_Panel2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Panel2");
        }
```

After your further comments, I've edited the below to show how to manually bind the mouse click events of the 2 panels of your dynamically added container.

```
private void splitContainerHorizontalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SplitContainer spltcnt = new SplitContainer();
            spltcnt.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            spltcnt.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            spltcnt.SplitterWidth = 4;
            spltcnt.Visible = true;
            spltcnt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(731, 615);
            spltcnt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            spltcnt.SplitterDistance = 351;

            //Manually bind the mouse click events.
            spltcnt.Panel1.MouseClick += Panel1OnMouseClick;
            spltcnt.Panel2.MouseClick += Panel2OnMouseClick;

            Controls.Add(spltcnt);
        }

        private void Panel1OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Panel1");
        }

        private void Panel2OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Panel2");
        }
```

You can of course call the mouse click handler methods anything you like.

Thanks

Comment: private void splitContainerHorizontalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      SplitContainer spltcnt = new SplitContainer();
            spltcnt.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            spltcnt.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            spltcnt.SplitterWidth = 4;
            spltcnt.Visible = true;
            spltcnt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(731, 615);
            spltcnt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            spltcnt.SplitterDistance = 351;
            Controls.Add(spltcnt);
        }

Comment: That's good news. Don't forget to select as the answer and upvote! Cheers

Comment: I would Like do spliter vertical or horizontal in one panel

Comment: @BirameBa - Just change the Orientation property to horizontal or vertical on the container.

Comment: I say after creating the first spliter i want to create a second spliter in a first panel

Comment: @BirameBa - Err pass.. sorry.. I've only used them on a basic level!